# system.string[] /value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'String()' in selected Index in listbox vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, selectedindexchanged

This is a program that I created in Visual Basic Window Form Application that uses two listboxes, one for Months and the other for Birthstones. When the user clicks a Birthstone a corresponding month is displayed in the lblDescription control, or when the user clicks a Month in the _strMonths listbox a corresponding Birthstone is displayed in the lblDescription. The program was working but I accidentally deleted it and now I don't remember the exact code anymore. I've been at it for a week now to recreate it but to no avail. I've researched SelectedIndex Property but everything I've seen so far is about the SelectedIndex Property being an integer but mine is a string. So I'm coming to the forum for help. The code is simple. I added a MsgBox(_intFill) which shows all the birthstones. I'm almost there, but no cigar yet.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmBirthstones
    'Declare class variables
    Private _strStones(11) As String
    Private _strMonths(11) As String
    Public Shared _intFill As String
    Public Shared _selectedIndex As String

    Private Sub frmBirthstones_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Array items for Brith Stones
        _strStones(0) = "Garnet"
        _strStones(1) = "Amethyst"
        _strStones(2) = "Aquamarine"
        _strStones(3) = "Diamond"
        _strStones(4) = "Emerald"
        _strStones(5) = "Pearl"
        _strStones(6) = "Ruby"
        _strStones(7) = "Peridot"
        _strStones(8) = "Sapphire"
        _strStones(9) = "Opal"
        _strStones(10) = "Topaz"
        _strStones(11) = "Turquoise"
        'Array items for Months
        _strMonths(0) = "January"
        _strMonths(1) = "February"
        _strMonths(2) = "March"
        _strMonths(3) = "April"
        _strMonths(4) = "May"
        _strMonths(5) = "June"
        _strMonths(6) = "July"
        _strMonths(7) = "August"
        _strMonths(8) = "September"
        _strMonths(9) = "October"
        _strMonths(10) = "November"
        _strMonths(11) = "December"

        'Makes label Description visible
        lblDescription.Visible = True

        For Each _intFill In _strStones
            'fills listbox with Birthstones
            lstStones.Items.Add(_intFill)
         MsgBox(_intFill)

        Next
        For Each _intFill In _strMonths
            'fills listbox with Months
            lstMonths.Items.Add(_intFill)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstStones_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstStones.SelectedIndexChanged
        'When user click or selects a Birthstone in this listbox a corresponding Month for the Birthstone is selected

        '_strStones = _intFill
        'Doesn't work
        lblDescription.Text = _strStones.ToString() & "is the Birthstone for the month of " & _strMonths.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstMonths_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstMonths.SelectedIndexChanged
        'When user click or selects a Month in this listbox a corresponding Birthstone for that Month is selected

        '_strMonths = 
        lblDescription.Text = _strMonths.ToString() & "is the Month for the Birthstone " & _strStones.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No, the SelectedIndex property is most certainly an Integer.  You are not using it, using an array's ToString() method makes no sense.  You need strsStones(lstStones.SelectedIndex).ToString(), easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmBirthstones
    Private _strStones(11) As String
    Private _strMonths(11) As String

    Private Sub frmBirthstones_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Array items for Brith Stones
        _strStones(0) = "Garnet"
        _strStones(1) = "Amethyst"
        _strStones(2) = "Aquamarine"
        _strStones(3) = "Diamond"
        _strStones(4) = "Emerald"
        _strStones(5) = "Pearl"
        _strStones(6) = "Ruby"
        _strStones(7) = "Peridot"
        _strStones(8) = "Sapphire"
        _strStones(9) = "Opal"
        _strStones(10) = "Topaz"
        _strStones(11) = "Turquoise"
        'Array items for Months
        _strMonths(0) = "January"
        _strMonths(1) = "February"
        _strMonths(2) = "March"
        _strMonths(3) = "April"
        _strMonths(4) = "May"
        _strMonths(5) = "June"
        _strMonths(6) = "July"
        _strMonths(7) = "August"
        _strMonths(8) = "September"
        _strMonths(9) = "October"
        _strMonths(10) = "November"
        _strMonths(11) = "December"



        'Makes label Description visible
        lblDescription.Visible = True


        'fills listbox with Birthstones
        lstStones.Items.AddRange(_strStones)


        'fills listbox with Months
        lstMonths.Items.AddRange(_strMonths)




    End Sub

    Private Sub lstStones_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lstStones.SelectedIndexChanged
        lblDescription.Text = _strStones(lstStones.SelectedIndex).ToString() & " is the Birthstone for the month of " & _strMonths(lstStones.SelectedIndex).ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstMonths_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lstMonths.SelectedIndexChanged
        lblDescription.Text = _strMonths(lstMonths.SelectedIndex).ToString() & " is the Month for the Birthstone " & _strStones(lstMonths.SelectedIndex).ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Maybe this is what you want to do.